# Using int and str with print

Tags: python-3.x

No matter how I do this, I get an error.  What am I missing?

I have tried all of the variations I know how to do, but I think I need to do something with the variables but when you input a number, I would imagine it stores it as an integer...

```py
first = input("Enter first number...")  # I input 5
second = input("Enter second number...")  # I input 6
operator = input("Spell out: add, subtract, multiply, or divide..."  # I input add

if operator == "add":
    print("Your answer is " + (int(first) + int(second)))
```

I have also tried:

```
if operator == "add":
   print("Your answer is " + (str(first) + str(second)))
```

and other variations...

If I do:
`print("Your answer is " + str(5 + 6))` it works

but:
`print("Your answer is " + str(first + second)))` doesn't work...

I would expect when the user inputs numbers it stores "first" and "second" as integers. Therefore, I can use "first" and "second" as if they were numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input returns a string, if you want an integer you have to do it yourself

`first = int(input("Enter first number..."))`

Also do yourself a favor and use f-strings, they are much more readable.

`print(f"Your answer is {first + second}")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do `print` like this

```
first = int(input("Enter first number..."))  # I input 5
second = int(input("Enter second number..."))  # I input 6
operator = input("Spell out: add, subtract, multiply, or divide...")  # I input add

if operator == "add":
    print("Your answer is ", first + second)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
print("You're answer is ",  (int(first) + int(second)))
```

You are trying to concatenate `string + integer`